# Generate 3000 different 14-digit numbers in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to create PINs numbers with 14 digits. I want to insert 3000 different pin numbers and then insert them into mysql. The below codes will insert only 120 or 127 random numbers instead of 3000 and stop. It also loops for longer time before giving that 127 numbers. And what I want is 3000 random numbers.

This is my code:

```
<form method="post" action=""> <table border=1> <tr>

 <td> <input type="text" name="num" placeholder="Enter total number to be generated e.g 3000" required></td>
                </tr>

            <td> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" value="Generate Pin">  </td>
            <tr>
                <td></table></form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $num = $_POST['num'];    
       for ($index = 0; $index < $num; $index++) {    
           $rand1 = rand(1000000, 9999999); 
           $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' ") or die 
          (mysql_error());
          if(mysql_num_rows($check)>0){
          $index-=1; 
          } 
           $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO  pins(randi) VALUES('$rand1')"; } } ?>
```

Comment: [You asked this already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58186024/1415724).

Comment: The guru here wants you to try and ask a better question. How do I generate a random 14 digit number? How do I loop 3000 times? How do I properly execute a query?  - to which the answers will be [RTM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php), [RTM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [RTM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Why are you using random 7-digit numbers if you want 14-digit?

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop but instead use [while()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: If you want to generate a bunch of values and jam them in the database, regardless of if they were already there or not, use `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` where `IGNORE` means "ignore duplication errors". Set a `UNIQUE` index on that column to avoid duplicates.

Comment: It's also worth noting if you want a 14-digit random value `rand` can't get you there, not even close. It will only generate values as large as `getrandmax()` which can be as low as 32,768.

Answer (score -1):

Try next:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // amount of numbers
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    // array of different numbers    
    $num_ar = [];
         // infinity loop
         for ( ; ; ) {    
             // random number
             $rand1 = rand(1000000, 9999999); 
             // 14-digits
             //$rand1 = rand(10000000000000, 99999999999999);  
             // if it is a different number
             if(!in_array($rand1,$num_ar)) {

                 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  pins(randi) VALUES('$rand1')";
                 array_push($num_ar,$rand1);
             }
             // stop the loop
             if (count($num_ar) == $num) break; 

         } 

    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // amount of numbers
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    // array of different numbers    
    $num_ar = [];
         // while loop
         while (count($num_ar) !== $num) {    
             // random number
             $rand1 = rand(1000000, 9999999); 
             // 14-digits
             //$rand1 = rand(10000000000000, 99999999999999);  
             // if it is a different number
             if(!in_array($rand1,$num_ar)) {

                 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  pins(randi) VALUES('$rand1')";
                 array_push($num_ar,$rand1);
             }

         } 

    }
?>
```